# SQL statement to find batting average from Access Database

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am creating a Visual Basic program with Microsoft Access Database.

The database has two tables.

- Table 1 called `Players` with Name, Hits, atBats and Team columns
- Table 2 called `Teams` with Team and League columns

I need help writing a SQL statement to find the player with the highest batting average from a specific league *National* or *American* league.

The `Batting Average` formula is `hits` divided by `atBats`.

**Code:**

```
SELECT 
    name, (hits / atBats) AS bAVG 
FROM 
    Players 
INNER JOIN 
    Teams ON Teams.team = Players.Team 
WHERE 
    Teams.league = 'American' 
    AND bAVG = (SELECT MAX(bAVG) FROM Players);
```

I think the problem is with the alias column `bAVG`.

Comment: What have you tried?  Seems like a pretty basic query -- `join`, `max` and `group by` might help...

Comment: my query is giving error.

Comment: Please post relevant code. As is, your question is likely to attract close and down votes. Also, what language are you using? [tag:vba] is different from [tag:vb.net].

Comment: my query is giving error. i wrote 
"SELECT name from Players, (hits/atBats) as bAVG 
FROM Players 
INNER JOIN Teams 
ON Teams.team = Players.Team
WHERE Teams.league = 'American'
AND bAVG = (select MAX(bAVG from Players));"

Comment: Next time, don't post codes on comment. Instead, edit the question and add it there. You can edit your question any number of times.

Comment: ok thanks. i am using VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no column bAVG in the joined table, hence the error. You can use something like:

> SELECT name from Players, (hits/atBats) as bAVG FROM Players INNER
>   JOIN Teams ON Teams.team = Players.Team WHERE Teams.league =
>   'American' AND (hits/atBats) = (select MAX((hits/atBats) from
>   Players));

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `order by` and `top`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 name, (hits/atBats) AS bAVG
FROM Players INNER JOIN
     Teams
     ON Teams.team = Players.Team
WHERE Teams.league = 'American'
ORDER BY hits/atBats DESC;
```